# Find number of sequences $ \langle A_1,...,A_k \rangle $

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

Find number of sequences $$ \langle A_1,...,A_k \rangle \text{ such that } A_i \subset \left\{1,...,n \right\} \text{ and } \left| A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_k \right| = r $$

### My solution

$$ \binom{n}{r} \cdot(2^{n-r} - (n-r) )^k   $$
1. $\binom{n}{r}$ we choose $r$ elements from $\left\{1,...,n \right\}$ which will be in every $A_i$

2. For each from $k$ sets we choose additional elements. It can be represented via functions:
$$ f: \left\{ A_1,...,A_k \right\} \rightarrow  \left\{1,...,n \right\} \setminus \text{ (choosen elements in step 1) } $$
It can be done in $2^{n-r}$ ways. We also should remove $n-r$ const functions: for example $$f(A_i) = p \in  \left\{1,...,n \right\} \setminus \text{ (choosen elements in step 1) }$$
because then our 
$$ \left| A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_k \right| \neq r $$ 
But answer is supposedly $$ \binom{n}{r} \cdot(2^{k} - 1 )^{n-r} $$

(I am not sure if it is correct answer because I found it on faculty website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is basically incorrect because you are doing the exercise as if the condition was:

$$|A_i \cap A_j|=r \ \ \forall i\neq j$$

The same element of the $n-r$ can be in more sets(but not in all of them). So the first part is correct:

$${n}\choose{r}$$

But then a possible strategy is a bijection. We write $1$ if we decide to insert an element in a set, and $0$ viceversa. So the possible binary numbers that we are creating are:

$$2^k$$

But from this binary numbers we must exclude $\underbrace{1...1}_{k}$ because this would mean that an element has been inserted in all of the sets(absurd):

$$2^k-1$$

This process must be repeated for each element ($n-r$):

$$(2^k-1)^{n-r}$$

So the final result is:

$${n\choose r} (2^k-1)^{n-r}$$

:)

Comment: Nice explanation! Thanks